# What is a good MySQL monitor for latest inserts?

Tags: mysql, monitoring

I am looking for a tool that will display the very latest information from a MySQL table and update every few seconds. The problem is I don't really know how to look for it, or what I am even really looking for outside of that!

I am currently running this query:

> SELECT hostName, email, info, MAX(id), time  FROM log u  WHERE time >=
>   DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)  GROUP BY hostName  ORDER BY `time`
>   DESC

Which gives me exactly what I want, but I'd like some sort of simple GUI to monitor the latest info..

Answer (score 0):

GUI? Why?

At the command line do this:

```
while true; do
mysql -u username -h hostname -p password -e "SELECT hostName, email, info, MAX(id), time FROM log u WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY hostName ORDER BY time DESC"
sleep 5
done
```